# Toggle Sidenav element from other module

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm doing my first steps in the Angular world, and I'm involved on a project that have the need to toggle side navigation element from a button that are on a different module of sidenav element. In particular, I'm using Angular Material for UI and the element for that sidenav that I'm currently using is mat-sidenav.

The question is, which is the good way to intercept this click event from a component that is on a different module of the sidenav that has to toggle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is already rolling and a large chunk of code is already produced then I would just create a service that stores this toggle state and inject it into both modules that need it. Most preferably this service will live in a shared module.

If the project has just kicked off consider looking at [ngrx store](https://github.com/ngrx/store), using that you would store a toggle boolean in state, on button click update toggle state and have your navigation element respond to the toggle state accordingly.

In any case its really up to the needs of your project. If its a simple project then go for the first option.

Comment: Thank your for your response, this project that I'm doing is for my own to train on Angular, so may be I will try both ways for practice, but I thing that ngrx for a react response could be really interesting. Many thanks.

Comment: glad to help :)